# Adding functions to Python Shell

Tags: python, function, terminal

Let's say I define the following function:

```
def roots(a,b,c):
    top = (b*b - 4*a*c)**0.5
    p1 = (- b + ( top ) )/(2*a)
    p2 = (- b - ( top ) )/(2*a)
    print(p1)
    print(p2)
```

I want to be able to call `roots(a,b,c)` inside the python shell. How can I accomplish this?

I expect the result to be something like.

```
Python 3.8.6 (tags/v3.8.6:db45529, Sep 23 2020, 15:52:53) [MSC v.1927 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32                                                                                                                                     
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.                                                                                                                                                             
>>> roots(2,3,1)
-0.5
-1.0
>>>
```

Comment: If you run the script containing the function as  `python3 -i your_file.py` it opens an interpreter session with the function available in scope. Otherwise you can just start an interpreter and run `from your_file import roots` which should be enough.

Comment: Sweet Thanks! I think for my purposes this will be fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your functions are defined in a python script `functions.py`, you have two options:

1. Run your script with `-i` flag to start an interactive session using `python3 -i functions.py`. This opens an interactive session with the functions in `functions.py` available in scope.
2. Alternatively, in the same directory containing `functions.py`, just start an interpreter and run `from functions import roots`.